# How to find all the ways the numbers in an array can be added together

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers and I want to see what all the values would be if I added together a pair in the array e.g.

```
function myFunction(numbers) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]);
  }
}

myFunction([1, 2, 3]);
```

This returns 3 and 5 but is there a way to also get 4? like I get 1 + 2 and 2 + 3 but how do I get 1 + 3? So:

```
function myFunction(numbers) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]);
  }

  console.log(numbers[0] + numbers[numbers.length - 1]);
}

myFunction([1, 2, 3]);
```

This would work but if you had 4 numbers it would be missing one

Comment: what is `addPairs` function?

Comment: use reduce method

Comment: Generate all unique combinations of two elements or more for the array and then add them together and return that array.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: I added an improved answer. the answer you selected does not work for arrays with more than three elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm iterating over the indexes i and j such that the pairs make up a triangle in a matrix of pairs.

```js
function myFunction(numbers) {
  let allNumbers = [];
  for (i in numbers)
    for (j in numbers)
      if (j > i) {
        allNumbers.push(numbers[j] + numbers[i]);
      }

  console.log(allNumbers)
}

myFunction([1, 2, 3, 5]);
```

Comment: This is can also be used for like a triad finder you just need another for loop.